# Page not loading after Postback event completes - ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a Javascript function on a button click with a POST to a WebMethod. After getting the response back; which is a redirect URL, the code goes to the IsPostBack event of the redirected page but that page never loads. I have written redirects all over the place but somehow this one just stays on the page it is called from.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyProfile.aspx/UpdateProfile_Clicked",
    async: false,
    data: parms,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {

        if (response.d != '') {
            alert("Your profile has been updated.");

            // response.d = "SubmitRequest.aspx"
            var data = response.d;
            if (data.indexOf("aspx", 0) > -1) {
                redirect(data);
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
    error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        LogAjaxErrorToServer(httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown, parms, "UpdateProfile_Clicked");
    }
});


function redirect(url) {
if (url == "") { return false; }
var indx = window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/', 0);
if (indx < 0) { indx = 0; }
var local = window.location.pathname.substr(0, indx);
local += "/" + url;
location.href = local;
return false;
}
```

So the code does go to the (!IsPostBack) for SubmitRequest.aspx but stays on the Profile.aspx. What am I missing? Thank you in advance for helping me

- May

Comment: Have you tried document.location.href?

Comment: Yes, tried that as well but same thing...